# Grails menu with profiling

Tags: security, grails, menu, grails-plugin

There are several grails menu plugins, for example the Navigation plugin. I need to show to user only those menu items that he can access according to his user profile. What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Is there a menu plugin that can integrate with some of grails security plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [navigation plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/navigation) has an example of using `isVisible` to conditionally hide menu items. If you're using the Spring Security plugin, then you could combine this with methods on the [SpringSecurityUtils](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.3%20SpringSecurityUtils) or on the injected [SpringSecurityService](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.2%20SpringSecurityService) bean:

```
def springSecurityService
// ...
static navigation = [
    [group:'userOptions', action:'login', order: 0, isVisible: { SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') }],
    [action:'logout', order: 99, isVisible: { springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() }]
]
```

Alternatively, Spring security comes with [some tags](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.1%20SecurityTagLib) that will render the tag body only if the user is/is not logged in, with what roles, etc., so you could just hand roll your menu items like this:

```
<sec:ifAllGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN">
  // Render <g:link../> to an admin page here.
</sec:ifAllGranted>
```